# Error resolving version for 'org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 2.1

Tags: gwt, maven, build

I am getting following error while building my pom.xml file with maven.

```
Error resolving version for 'org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 2.1
```

Below is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>WoofArchetypeResult</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WoofArchetypeResult</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <gwt.version>2.5.0</gwt.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.officefloor.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>officeplugin_woof</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Remove if running stand alone -->
            <groupId>net.officefloor.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>officeplugin_woof_servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <!-- Standard JVM for compilation -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <!-- Compile GWT Java to JavaScript -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Test WoOF within Servlet Container -->
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
                <configuration>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>18080</port>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <stopPort>18181</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>officefloor</stopKey>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Run tests against WoOF within Servlet Container -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After hitting "mvn install" command on cmd . I am getting above Build Error.
My maven version is 2.0.11

Please help me

Comment: You need Mavev version 2.1 or up. If you have already then issue has already been addressed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323955/gwt-maven-plugin-plugin-requires-maven-version-2-1

Comment: @Imounir I am not using ant task

Comment: Why are you using such an extremely old Maven version. Use maven 3.0.4....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words you need to USE upgraded version of Maven. If you are stuck with maven 2 then atleast upgrade to latest version of Maven 2 i.e **Release 2.2.1**.

If you can please upgrade to Maven 3 latest **Release 3.0.4**.

*With the amount of effort you might spend to make old stuff work you might as well try putting it in building new stuff.*